# When rotating shapes, vertices are just slightly off

Tags: python, animation, manim

I'm working on a manim challenge from this video: https://youtu.be/HKPm8FZYaqI?t=700. The challenge is to code the animation which starts at 11:40 and ends at 11:49.

I got up to the point where the triangles are rotated and copied over to the second square, but for some reason they are just the ones that I had to rotate are just ever so slightly off, while the ones I didn't have to rotate seem to be perfect.

Look at this image: [image]

The triangles fit perfectly inside the square to the right. But in the right square, the ones that were rotated (1 and 4) do not. Below is a closeup of what I mean for triangle number 1:[image]

Of course, this is how I want it to look:[image]
The dimensions of the shapes and maybe the colours are a little different, but that is because this is the solution of the author of the video, and the previous was my attempt. I don't care about that, I only care about why the triangles don't fit perfectly in my attempt like they do here.
Zooming in on this picture, we see that the triangles do indeed fit perfectly:[image]

Any insight into why this is happening would be very much appreciated!

The source code for my animation is this:

```
class Pythagoras(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        title = TextMobject("Pythagorean Theorem")
        title.to_edge(UL)

        pre_square = Polygon(
            [-2, 2, 0],
            [2, 2, 0],
            [2, -2, 0],
            [-2, -2, 0],
            color=WHITE
        )

        self.wait()


        square2 = Polygon(
            [-1.41, 1.41, 0],
            [1.41, 1.41, 0],
            [1.41, -1.41, 0],
            [-1.41, -1.41, 0]

        )
        square2.rotate(PI/6)

        triangle1 = Polygon(
            [-2, 2, 0],
            [-2 + math.sqrt(6), 2, 0],
            [-2, 2 - math.sqrt(2), 0],
            color=YELLOW
        )

        triangle2 = Polygon(
            [2, 2, 0],
            [-2 + math.sqrt(6), 2, 0],
            [2, 2 - math.sqrt(6), 0],
            color=YELLOW
        )

        triangle3 = Polygon(
            [2, 2 - math.sqrt(6), 0],
            [2, -2, 0],
            [2 - math.sqrt(6), -2, 0],
            color=YELLOW
        )

        triangle4 = Polygon(
            [-2, 2 - math.sqrt(2), 0],
            [-2, -2, 0],
            [2 - math.sqrt(6), -2, 0],
            color=YELLOW
        )

        triangles = [triangle1, triangle2, triangle3, triangle4]
        for triangle in triangles:
            triangle.set_fill(YELLOW, 0.6)

        self.play(Write(title), ShowCreation(pre_square), ShowCreation(triangle1), ShowCreation(triangle2), ShowCreation(triangle3), ShowCreation(triangle4))

        self.wait()

        group = VGroup(pre_square, triangle1, triangle2, triangle3, triangle4)

        self.play(ApplyMethod(group.to_edge, LEFT, {"buff": 1.6}))
        self.wait()

        square3 = pre_square.copy()

        self.play(ApplyMethod(square3.shift, RIGHT * 7))

        triangle2.generate_target()
        triangle2.target.shift(RIGHT * (7- math.sqrt(6)))

        triangle1.generate_target()
        triangle1.target = triangle2.target.copy().rotate(PI) 

        triangle3.generate_target()
        triangle3.target.shift(RIGHT * 7)

        triangle4.generate_target()
        triangle4.target = triangle3.target.copy().rotate(PI)


        self.play(MoveToTarget(triangle1.copy()), MoveToTarget(triangle2.copy()), MoveToTarget(triangle3.copy()), MoveToTarget(triangle4.copy()))

        self.wait()
```

Comment: That looks like an artifact from a miter style line join -- see here for an example of it in SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linejoin

Comment: Thanks for your comment, maybe I should look into how to remove it in manim then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the thickness of the VMobjects, by default it is 4, if you change it to 2 or 1 (in the solution that I give is 1) those corners are removed. Add this in your `for`:

```py
        for triangle in triangles:
            triangle.set_fill(YELLOW, 0.6)
            triangle.set_stroke(None,1.5)
            #or
            #triangle.set_stroke(width=1.5)
            #it is the same
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually nothing wrong with the code just how these triangles are drawn. The border around the triangle have width which causes the artifact. If you remove the border or consider the border as the range of the triangle the problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't find any documentation for manim. Do you mind telling me how I actually remove the border? I thought perhaps i set the color attribute to "#00FFFFFF" (transparent), but it seems it only accepts 3/6 hex digits.

Comment: @ChristofferCorfieldAakre I'm also not familiar with manim. The name for the size of the border is often referred as stroke width in graphics. Maybe you can search in that direction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.